# Craft Ordering breaking nth child?

Tags: entries, categories

For some reason, when outputting 'featured' tagged items, It's ordering them I presume by alphabetical values which is breaking the nth-child CSS set on every 3rd element? Is there anyway to stop this?

**Getting Tagged Categories**

```
  {% set tag = craft.tags.slug('featured').first() %}
  {% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo(tag) %}

  {% if categories|length %}
    {% for category in categories.limit(3) %}

      <a class="university-widget w-inline-block" href="{{ category.url }}">

        {% for asset in category.universityImage %}
          <div class="university-widget-image" style="background-image:url({{ asset.url }})"></div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="university-widget-content">
          {% for asset in category.universityLogo %}
            <img class="university-widget-logo" src="{{asset.url}}" height="40">
          {% endfor %}
          <p class="small-paragraph university-widget-description-test" id="university-widget-description">{{ category.description }}</p>
        </div>
      </a>

    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

**CSS**

```
.university-widget:nth-child(3n)
{
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

Picture Evidence

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why Craft would be breaking a CSS rule, you're outputting three items and is it outputting the 3 items on the page?

If yes, then the CSS rule might need to be fixed. If not, then I don't understand your problem.